# OS X Mountain Lion Crashes When Installs Xcode

Tags: crash, osx-mountain-lion, xcode

So I just recently upgraded to Mountain Lion and so I needed to upgrade Xcode to the newest version. Well everything was going fine during the download but then about 1 minute after it started installing my computer just instantly crashed and rebooted. When I got back into OS X, I was greeted with this error:

```
Your computer was restarted because of a problem

Interval Since Last Panic Report:  1349 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          3
Anonymous UUID:                    D15D8585-7FF2-6F6E-F636-ADC39FD0D6BF

Thu Nov  8 15:55:34 2012
panic(cpu 7 caller 0xffffff8027b1ddfa): "fsevents: copy_out_kfse: asked to copy out an invalid event (kfse 0xffffff80df7f4380, refcount 0 fref ptr 0xdeadbeef)\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2050.18.24/bsd/vfs/vfs_fsevents.c:1267
Backtrace (CPU 7), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80defe3b10 : 0xffffff8027a1d626 
0xffffff80defe3b80 : 0xffffff8027b1ddfa 
0xffffff80defe3de0 : 0xffffff8027b1d493 
0xffffff80defe3e60 : 0xffffff8027d76abe 
0xffffff80defe3f00 : 0xffffff8027d768e2 
0xffffff80defe3f60 : 0xffffff8027de1533 
0xffffff80defe3fb0 : 0xffffff8027acea1d 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: SmartwareServerA

Mac OS version:
12C60

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 69A5853F-375A-3EF4-9247-478FD0247333
Kernel slide:     0x0000000027800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8027a00000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5695620123152
last loaded kext at 4171716596146: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs  1.8 (addr 0xffffff7fa9e31000, size 229376)
last unloaded kext at 1454483445663: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7fa9e2e000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.2.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.2.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.2.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.2.4
com.logmein.hamachi 1.0
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.5.2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.8
com.apple.filesystems.exfat 1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.ntfs  3.10
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.69
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver  4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothA2DPAudioDriver 4.0.9f33
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.1f2
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.1f2
com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.2d0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.2.11
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  235.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 235.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.5b3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   602.15.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 19.0.26
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.1f2
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    8.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   8.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.2.11
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.5
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.2.0d16
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 235.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   500.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 344
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 6 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.81.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.9f33 10885, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS727550A9E362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 3
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0245, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 6
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

If I try to reinstall (including re-download) it does the same thing. Does anyone know about this problem or how to fix it? I've searched Google and have not come across anything like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever see's this I figured out what it was. It was the VirtualBox kexts in /Library/Extensions/. Once I removed those the installation went smoothly.